# Vhost in Apache only working locally?

Tags: xampp

Ok, I have added lines like:

```
127.0.0.1   somedomain.com
```

Or some other domain that points to my routers IP, and is forwarded, but I get to the main site, but I want it to go to the subfolder I defined in my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost  somedomain.com:80

<VirtualHost somedomain.com:80>
 DocumentRoot "D:/Apps/xampp/htdocs/somedomain"
 ServerName somedomain.com
 ServerAlias somedomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So, locally somedomain.com works, just remotely it goes to the root htdocs. So If I use a *:80 wildcard I works, but then everything points to the subfolder and all the other vhosts seem to get ignored.

Any Idea why this is?

Answer (score 1):

127.0.0.1 is not going to work for any external connections as it is just local address which each host has it assigned to itself.

I would suggest to change httpd.conf  so, apache process listens on your IP address assigned by DHCP

Comment: ^ Also, a hosts file only works locally. An external machine won't be able to use anothers hosts file.

Comment: So, I'll leave the hosts file alone, I just followed some instructions somewhere to get vhosts to work on Xampp apache server..

Comment: Wait, m1k3y02, are you saying I have to put the <virtualhost> stuff in httpd.conf instead of the httpd-vhosts.conf?

Comment: no, what I was trying to say is, that wherever you have IP address declaration it should be changed to IP address other than 127.0.0.1 as it is just loop back. So, it is the same like you would access http://localhost - it won't work from external/remote machine, which in your case is your host. localhost/127.0.0.1 each time references to the machine you operating at. i.e. ping localhost will ping the computer where you executed command. do ipconfig or ifconfig -a from command line and take the IP other than 127.0.0.1 and replace it in httpd.conf

Comment: Ok, turns out, yes, I used the wrong config all along, It was a combination of using the hosts file at the same time.